# Replacing entire word in mysql with wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a value like "opening 01-01-2001" in a field, i want to remove all values like that, getting a result like "opening ".

Actually i'm using this code to replace words:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, 'word', '');
```

Is there something like wildcards? I.E.:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, '%*-*-*%', '');
```

To remove all entire word using only the starting character or the word mask?

Comment: No, in MySQL there is no built-in function that could replace a portion of a string based on a pattern.

Comment: Do all of your "problem" fields have the word `'opening'` in them? Or are you looking for a more general solution that you can apply in other situations?